# Convergence rate of general Markov chains

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, jordan-normal-form

lets say we have a Markov chain with $\pi^T = ¸\pi^T P$, but we do not know anything about $P$ unless that the chains has a unique stationary distribution $p_*$ that it converges to.

Let $e_t = p_t - p_*$ be the error.
I would like to know how fast the error converges to zero.
So what is $f$ in $\|e_t\|_2 \leq f(t) \|e_0\|_2$

If we assume that $P$ has an Eigendecomposition it"s easy. But how do you do it in the general case?